# SearchView fires two Intents to SearchActivity

Tags: android, searchview

Currently i am testing my application with espresso tests, however the SearchView fires two identical Intents for the SearchResultActivity (Activity which performs the search and displays the result). Why are there two intents fired and not only a single one?

In my test i get the following error message:

```
android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 2 intents.

    IntentMatcher: (has component: has component with: class name: is "my.first.application.search.SearchResultActivity" package name: an instance of java.lang.String short class name: an instance of java.lang.String and has action: is "android.intent.action.SEARCH" and has extras: has bundle with: key: is "query" value: is "Baecker Neuss")

    Matched intents:
    -Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEARCH flg=0x10000000 cmp=my.first.application.MyApplication.lite.cpa/my.first.application.search.SearchResultActivity launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } (has extras) } handling packages:[[my.first.application.MyApplication.lite.cpa]], extras:[Bundle[{query=Baecker Neuss, user_query=Baecker Neuss}]])
    -Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEARCH flg=0x10000000 cmp=my.first.application.MyApplication.lite.cpa/my.first.application.search.SearchResultActivity launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } (has extras) } handling packages:[[my.first.application.MyApplication.lite.cpa]], extras:[Bundle[{query=Baecker Neuss, user_query=Baecker Neuss}]])

    Recorded intents:
    -Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEARCH flg=0x10000000 cmp=my.first.application.MyApplication.lite.cpa/my.first.application.search.SearchResultActivity launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } (has extras) } handling packages:[[my.first.application.MyApplication.lite.cpa]], extras:[Bundle[{query=Baecker Neuss, user_query=Baecker Neuss}]])
    -Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEARCH flg=0x10000000 cmp=my.first.application.MyApplication.lite.cpa/my.first.application.search.SearchResultActivity launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } (has extras) } handling packages:[[my.first.application.MyApplication.lite.cpa]], extras:[Bundle[{query=Baecker Neuss, user_query=Baecker Neuss}]])
    at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1567)
    at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:90)
    at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:52)
    at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:314)
    at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:291)
    at android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended(Intents.java:185)
    at android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended(Intents.java:167)
    at my.first.application.MyApplicationTest.testOSMSearch(SGJMobileTest.java:48)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:433)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:58)
    at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:375)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1967)
```

This is the test which fails:

```
@Test
    public void testOSMSearch() {
        String searchQuery = "Baecker Neuss";
        Intents.init();
        onView(withId(R.id.toolbar_search))
                .perform(click(), typeSearchView(searchQuery), pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
        intended(allOf(
                hasComponent(SearchResultActivity.class.getName()),
                hasAction(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH),
                hasExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, searchQuery)));
        Intents.release();
    }
```

Android Manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MyApplication"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".search.SearchResultActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".search.SearchResultActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
```

searchable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="@string/osmSearch"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Initialisation of the SearchView:

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, Activity activity) {
        activity.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_toolbar_menu, menu);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.toolbar_search).getActionView();
        ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(activity, SearchResultActivity.class);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(cn));
        return true;
    }
```

The workflow in the application is correct, however due to the two Intents the activity has to handle two Intents. Has anyone a suggestion why there are two Intents fired or a solution how to fix this?